# sIFR3 and line-height/leading

Tags: sifr, css

I've successfully implemented sIFR3 using the nightlies from the end of Oct. All is well and much easier to work with than sIFR2 except where it comes to line-height.

I was able to deal with my headings fine. But I have a pullquote that needs *more* line-height/leading and though I've read through support and see that it needs to be applied to the .sIFR-root, it's not working. Is there something funky I don't know about?

Here's my code:

sIFR.replace(fedraBook, {
  selector: '.callout p',
  css: '.sIFR-root { background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #968b85; leading: 3.5;}'
});

I had the leading at 1.5 but changed to 3.5 just to see if I could get it to vary at all. It does not.

I tried also affecting it with this CSS selector with no joy:

.sIFR-active .callout p {
  font-size: 1.6em; 
  padding-top: 7px;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  }

Does anyone have any ideas here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

i know my answer is not of much help but I too have had this issue. there is very little documentation on the subject. as far as I know, sIFR does not support true line-height. It uses the height of the flash object and the font-size to set the line-height. http://tests.novemberborn.net/sifr3/experiments/tuning/line-height.html